# Abstract controller method fail to be recognized while concrete one does

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, controller, asp.net-web-api-routing

So I am doing little refactoring in our Web API project and I noticed that it will be good to extract one of the controllers in abstract class with all needed attributes so what I did is:

- extracted abstract class and method out of my existing controller:

  ```
  [RoutePrefix("api/auth")]
  public class AdminController : BaseAdminController
  ```

So `BaseAdminController` looks like this:

```
public abstract class BaseAdminController : BaseApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("validatetoken")]
    public abstract IHttpActionResult ValidateToken(string token);
}
```

This is the routing I use:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    // Web API configuration and services
    // Web API routes
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/"
    );
}
```

Now I noticed that when testing the code with abstract controller it gives throws:

> No type was found that matches the controller named 'auth'

While same implementation but without abstract class and method works just fine.

I am testing with this url :

```
http://localhost:60747/api/auth/validatetoken?auth_token=117a2686-dad3-4b1e-a5eb-94aebed45d06
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Inherited attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.attributeusageattribute.inherited(v=vs.110).aspx) controls whether subclasses inherit any particular attribute from a superclass. The default value is true.

Unfortunately for your refactoring, both the [`RouteAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.routeattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) and [`RoutePrefixAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.routeprefixattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) attributes are sealed classses with `Inherited` = **false**. You'll need to specifically declare those attributes on all your concrete controller classes and methods.

Comment: I don't get it .. my `RoutePrefix` attribute is placed on my concrete class, whatelse is that I decompiled `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core.5.2.3\lib\net45\System.Web.Http.dll` (which was the assembly my project is using for this attribute) and RouteAttribute was marked with `Inherited = true` I am kinda surprised that msdn shows the opposite..

Comment: This answer is misguided. review linked duplicate.